# Trying to do discord.js on react emoji get dm

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How can I make a bot that send you a dm when you react on one or two emojis?
I'm not that good at JavaScript so I'm asking for your help.

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    if(message.author.bot)
    {
        if(message.embeds)
        {
            const embedMsg = message.embeds.find(msg => msg.title === 'server roles');
            if(embedMsg)
            {
                embedMsg.message.react('706754740767424572')
                .then(reaction => reaction.message.react('706761878721789982'))
                .then(msg => console.log("Deleted message"))
                .catch(err => console.error);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    if(message.content.toLowerCase() === '!roles')
    {
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
        embed.setTitle("server roles");
        embed.setColor("BLUE")
        embed.setDescription("<:Patreon:706754740767424572> - patreonas")
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
});


bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if(reaction.message.id !== '737968410377453578') return
    user.send('...')
    .catch(console.error)
  });
```

Comment: Please add details. What is your code supposed to do at the moment? Do you want to track only the emojis added to a specific message or all messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the bot event messageReactionAdd, you'll need to add that:

```
let msgId = [];

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if(message.content === "command") {
        message.channel.send(
            new discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor("embed")
                .setDescription("a sample descrption")
        ).then(message => {
            msgId.push(message.id);
            message.react("");
        })
    }
})

client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if(user.id !== bot.user.id) {
        if(reaction.message.id === msgId[0]) {
            user.send("the message sent to the person that had react");
        }
    }
});
```

That code's goal is to when a specific message is sent, send a message embed, then the bot push the new embed id to an array and add a reaction to this embed.

then when someone react to this reaction, if the author of this reaction is not the bot, then the bot send a message the person that reacted to the message embed.

Also, you should update your discord.js library to discord.js v12 using `npm update discord.js`